# Swagger UI for an Azure Function API app

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-functions, swagger-ui

I have implemented a REST API using Http triggered Azure functions. I already have an OpenAPI definition (yaml and json file) for the API.

The 'API definition' feature of the Function app additionally helps in generating OpenAPI definition from the functions. I would like to host the Swagger UI in the function app itself. It is easily doable with a WebAPI web app using Swashbuckle but could not get it to work in a Function App.

Is it possible to host the Swagger UI in a Function App so that the user can directly try it out in the browser, rather than having to import the definition in Postman.

Comment: @HelderSepu I spent hours trying to get the Swagger UI to work in a function app! Wonder if you even know what I'm talking about!

Comment: where did you get stuck? what error did you get?

Comment: There's no error. I just don't know how to go beyond generating the definition (yaml or json) to have the Swagger UI hosted in my Function app

Comment: [Vijay Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16827411) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69065666) saying "Microsoft recently announced the OpenAPI support on Azure Functions. [https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/create-and-publish-openapi-enabled-azure-functions-with-visual/ba-p/2381067?WT.mc_id=stackoverflow-0000-juyoo](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/create-and-publish-openapi-enabled-azure-functions-with-visual/ba-p/2381067?WT.mc_id=stackoverflow-0000-juyoo)"